# How to uncheck switch if server returns error?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a basic switcher from Material UI.

It has onChange event and is checked/unchecked on it. Also it send request to the server on Change.

What I can't figure out is how to uncheck it if my request to the server sent back an error.

My request to backend is a redux action, which calls `redux-logic` so I can't chain `.then` or `.catch`

I'm using Redux so I guess I can store successful/unsuccessful request there but I'm not sure how to use it then in component?

[code in sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-p9odo)

Comment: wait wait wait "My request to backend is not a promise". Explain please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your example code, you need to decide whether or not to toggle the `switch` state based on the result of the API call.  This means that in your `handleChange` method you should call the API prior to toggling the state, and if the API call fails, then don't change the state of the switch (and provide some notification to the user that it failed).

I have expanded your sandbox with a mock API call to demonstrate how this might work (there are many ways to do this).  The `mockApiCall` in my example will randomly return `true` or `false`, so you can see how it handles either case.  Just swap out my `mockApiCall` for dispatching an action through redux, but the premise should be pretty much the same.  [Working Example Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-ffqx7?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).

The key is to modify your `handleChange` similar to the below:

```
handleChange = async () => {
  this.setState({ busy: true });

  //REQUEST TO THE SERVER
  const result = await this.mockApiCall(1000);
  if (result === true) {
    console.log("Api Call Success");
    this.setState({ busy: false, switch: !this.state.switch });
  } else {
    console.log("Api Call Fail");
    this.setState({ busy: false });
  }
};
```

You can see I've added a `busy` property to the state to track when the API call is in-flight.  Additionally, you can disable the switch while it is busy, like follows:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Switch
        disabled={this.state.busy}
        checked={this.state.switch}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
      {this.state.busy && <span>Working...</span>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The sandbox above has the `mockApiCall` so you can see the whole thing working.